# Personalizar Vuetify-icon-picker

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

He implementado el componente vuetify-icon-picker pero intento personalizarlo ya que quiero aplicar los iconos de MDI y asignarlos con el atributo :icons
Pero no logro en primera cambiar el nombre de la cabecera de cada v-tab y cambiarlo a otro idioma o en su defecto sobreescribir el idioma ya que se encuentra en idioma oriental
Y segundo, al intentar poner los MDI en un array no se agrega o no se visualizan

Espero que alguien me pueda apoyar con esta duda o en su defecto saber si se puede o no

Esta desarrollado con vue 2

Comment: Y el código compadre? No podemos ayudarte si no nos ayudas con algo que tengas hecho o un ejemplo al menos.

Answer (score 0):

porque no mejor usas el v-icon? Instala la esta lib que tienémuchisimos iconos MDI.
https://pictogrammers.github.io/@mdi/font/6.5.95/

y podas ponerlos asi

```
                        <v-btn small elevation="10" :dark="true" color="white" v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
                        <v-icon left color="primary">mdi-cash-multiple</v-icon>
                        <span >texto</span>
                    </v-btn>
```